# Branching pipeline // fanout-fanin : Process each file in separate branch

Tags: apache-beam

The wordcount example is great -- but limited.

Imagine we want to transform each file in the `shakespeare` folder, and the processing is much more intense than counting words.

Is something like this possible within the same pipeline, without manually specifying the different branches?

#### Not This

```
# This processes all the files in the same "branch" in Dataflow.
p | beam.Create([/shakespeare/*.txt]) | MatchAll() | ...
```

#### Like This

```
                  ┌───────────────────────────┐
                  │ Start: /shakespeare/*.txt │
                  └────────────┬──────────────┘
                               │
                               │
                  ┌────────────▼──────────────┐
                  │ Expand glob (MatchAll)    │
                  └────────────┬──────────────┘
                               │
      ┌─────────┬──────────────┼────────┬──────────────┐
      │         │              │        │              │
┌─────▼─┐    ┌──▼────┐  ┌──────▼┐   ┌───▼───┐      ┌───▼─────┐
│ File1 │    │ File2 │  │ File3 │   │ File4 │  ... │ File123 │
└───┬───┘    └──┬────┘  └───┬───┘   └───┬───┘      └───┬─────┘
    │           │           │           │              │
    │           │           │           │              │
    │           │           │           │              │
┌───▼───┐    ┌──▼────┐  ┌───▼───┐   ┌───▼───┐      ┌───▼───┐
│ done  │    │ done  │  │ done  │   │ done  │      │ done  │
└───┬───┘    └───┬───┘  └───┬───┘   └───┬───┘      └───┬───┘
    │            │          │           │              │
    │            │          │           │              │
    └────────────┴──────────┴──┬────────┴──────────────┘
                               │
                        ┌──────▼──────┐
                        │Merge Results│
                        └─────────────┘
```

Comment: It would be helpful to understand why you need to process separate files in separate branches. Are the DoFns themselves parameterized by the file name/type?

Comment: Maybe I don't. I think I do because the data to read in each file is large, and each file has to then be merged with 1..N (typically about 20) smaller files. The end intent is "sub-pipelines" that will probably run on separate machines to avoid enormous GroupBy and manual partitioning.

Comment: DoFn execution is automatically processed across multiple machines, see, e.g. https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/no-shard-left-behind-dynamic-work-rebalancing-in-google-cloud-dataflow You should be fine with a single DoFn to process everything and letting the underlying system parallelize things physically.

Answer (score 0):

one solution that comes to my mind is to partition your collection into multiple collections.

Partition Separates elements in a collection into multiple output collections. The partitioning function contains the logic that determines how to separate the elements of the input collection into each resulting partition output collection.

see Apache beam doc for more info and sample:
https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/elementwise/partition/